# When the singular inner part disappear in inner outer factorization?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, hardy-spaces

I saw this remark in Hoffman's book - "Banach space of analytic function".

If $f$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$, the closure of $\mathbb{D}$; then in the inner-outer factorization $f$, it has has no singular inner part. I am struggling to prove this. Any kind of suggestion is welcome.

what I have found that, if $f$ is analytic analytic in a neighborhood of $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$, and $f$ is a inner function without zero in $\mathbb{D}$, then $f$ must be constant of modulus one. But in general I am not able to show that if I divide the function by its outer part why it still remains analytic in a neighborhood of $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$? If that is true then I am done. Am i going to right direction?

I have another question. If I start with a multiply connected domain $\Omega$ in complex plane instead of unit disk, we know that there is a inner outer factorization (upto modulus) for function in Hardy space $H^2(\Omega)$(Reference: "Function theory in plannar domain" by Fischer). Now again If a function $f$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $\bar{\Omega}$, does it necessarily follow that $f$ has no singular inner part?

Comment: Start with $f(z)=z-1$. If you write $f(z)=b(z)s(z)o(z)$ on the unit disk, where $b$ is a Blaschke product, $s(z)$ is a singular inner function and $o(z)$ is the outer part, then what is $s$?

Comment: In your case, as $f(z)=z-1$ has no zero in $\mathbb{D}$, $f(z)$ is itself an outer function. And hence  $s(z)$ will be $1$ in this case.

Comment: If $f$ is holomorphic on an open neighborhood of the closed unit disk, then you have two cases for zeros in the closed unit disk: in the open disk, and on the unit circle. Those inside the unit disk are part of a finite Blaschke product. Those on the unit circle you know how to handle. There are only a finite number of such zeros because how of $f$ extends to an open neighborhood of the disk. So, what's your conclusion?

Comment: Thanks, I think I got the answer. But what about in multiply connected domain? I hope this holds there also by similar kind of argument.

Comment: Factor out the zeros that lie in $\overline{\Omega}$. There can be only a finite number of them in a given component because $f$ is holomorphic on an open neighbhoord of $\overline{\Omega}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it.

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

With the help of T.A.E I think I got my answer.

As $f$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$, $f$ has finitely many zeros in $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$. Let $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ be the zeros of $f$ which lies on the circle.  So, $f$ can be written as 
\begin{align}
f= B F G
\end{align} where, $B$ is the finte Blaschke product, $F = \prod\limits _{i=1}^{n} (z-a_i)$  and $G$ is a holomorphic  in a neighbourhood $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ with no zeros in $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$.

Note that, as $G$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ and has no zeros in $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$, clearly  $\log|g|$ is harmonic in a neighborhood of $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$. So $G$ is outer.

Also using the fact, $\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\log (|\exp(it)-a|) dt = 0$, where $a$ is a point on the circle, we will have $(z-a)$ is  a outer function for $a$ lies on circle. As a consequence $F$ will be outer.

Hence $f$ has no singular inner part.